# Can't reset customer password in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, change-password

customer cant reset its password in magento2.Something went wrong while resetting the password.This issue comes while resetting the password. Please help me out in this point.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go To Admin Panel,

> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration ->
>   Password Options

Set Value to 0 for Max Number of Password Reset Requests field.
The default value is 5.

And Save Config Button.